# Custom entity generate process plugin gives error

Tags: 8, migrations

I am creating a custom process plugin. Which is inherited from the EntityGenerate plugin. In my custom plugin I want to call the EntityLookup tranform function. So I tried to inject the entity_lookup plugin into my custom plugin.

```
    class CustomEntityGenerate extends EntityGenerate {
      /**
       * The database connection.
       *
       * @var \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection
       */
      protected $database;
      /**
       * An instance of the entity_lookup process plugin.
       *
       * @var \Drupal\migrate\Plugin\MigrateProcessInterface
       */
      protected $entityLookupPlugin;
      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $pluginId, $pluginDefinition, MigrationInterface $migration = NULL) {
        $instance = parent::create($container, $configuration, $pluginId, $pluginDefinition, $migration);
    $instance->entityLookupPlugin = $instance->processPluginManager->createInstance('entity_lookup', $configuration, $migration);
    $instance->database = $container->get('database');
        return $instance;
      }



/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrateExecutable, Row $row, $destinationProperty) {
    $this->row = $row;
    $this->migrateExecutable = $migrateExecutable;
    // Creates an entity if the lookup determines it doesn't exist.
    if (!($result = $this->entityLookupPlugin->transform($value, $migrateExecutable, $row, $destinationProperty))) {
      $result = $this->generateEntity($value);
    }
    return $result;
  }
}
```

But when I try to execute the import, I am getting this error.

```
The "" entity type does not exist.
```

here is my migration yml code

```
keywords:
    - plugin: sub_process
      source: keyword
      process:
        value: Name
    - plugin: custom_entity_generate
      value_key: name
      bundle_key: vid
      bundle: keyword
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      ignore_case: true
```

when I use the entity_generate instead of custom_entity_generate then it works fine. What I am doing wrong here?

When I print `$this->lookupEntityType` in the entity_lookup's `transform` function. It prints the `taxonomy_term` . But when I print it in the entity_generate's `generateEntity` method, I am getting an empty string

Note: I am creating a custom process plugin, because I want to insert some data to the database if a terms does not exist and is created through the migration.

Comment: I don't quite understand your code. Why are you trying to inject the original entity lookup when you are directly extending it? You already have access to all its functions and variables through simple inheritance.

Comment: @Hudri I am inheriting from entity generate not from entity lookup. and entity generate is inhereted from entity lookup

Comment: IMHO you are over-engineering here. Maybe take a look at entity_lookup's transform function. It is not much more than a two-liner consisting of `$this->determineLookupProperties` and `$this->query`. Or maybe inhertit from entity_lookup instead of entity_generate.

Comment: Instead of injecting it, I called it directly `EntityLookup::transform` and now I am not getting that empty entity type error.